# Is the MW2 steam server still online?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

Some weeks ago I wanted to play MW2 multiplayer, but I saw '0 players currently playing'.

Could it possibly be that Infinity Ward has shut down the Modern Warfare 2 network for playing in lobbies?

*I know there are alternatives like IW4play (since alterIWnet is down 'cause of IW)*

Comment: MW2 servers are different for different platforms and run by different parties. Are you asking about [tag:ps3], [tag:xbox-360] or [tag:pc]?

Comment: PC network.. on steam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some bug with MW2 so the amount of players in game always shows up as 0/0.

If you try to enter a game you should still get in. There is no way of knowing if there is actually anyone in a certain game type so I'd recommend Free-for-all or Team Deathmatch to ensure you get into a game.

Comment: This bug seems to have been fixed as it now seems to show the number of people playing and not 0/0

Comment: There are still no players. But I could retry once again.

Comment: I took a screenshot just now it shows people online.
http://cloud-2.steampowered.com/ugc/576706603155165071/32A4EE3501BBA095B74299C3E4FD224442B205FE/

Answer (score 6):

No, Modern Warfare 2 is still a supported multiplayer game.  I'm guessing you had some type of network issue or encountered some sort of bug.

Modern Warfare 2 is still among the top 10 multiplayer PC games on Steam at the moment, going by the [Steam Game Stats](http://store.steampowered.com/stats/) - today its peak players was double that of Black Ops, but nowhere near the amount of players of MW3.

A recent [Major Nelson blog post](http://majornelson.com/2012/04/17/live-activity-for-week-of-april-9th/) shows that Modern Warfare 2 is still among the most played multiplayer games on Xbox Live as well.  (Also note that CoD4 and WaW are still supported games...)

There was some talk of shutting down the Black Ops servers on PSN a while back, which I believe was a reaction to the rampant cheating/griefing that occurred after the Playstation 3 firmware was hacked.  However, I do not believe a shutdown actually occurred.

Comment: I tried on different days and there was always this error. Now I deleted MW2, but I will try to reinstall MW2 and try it out again.

Answer (score 0):

They are definitely down. You can only play private servers with your friends, and friends of your friends. The only way you can get to a lobby is if you land in somebody's modded lobby.

Answer (score -4):

I think they are down. I tried to join a game and it said no one was online and when I tried to join a match it said communication with the XBOX Live servers are down or something like that. I was on Xbox One S  using backwards compatibility to play.

Comment: And what makes you think that was not a temporary or local error? Answers should be based on facts and consistency; this sounds like an opinion.